# How to migrate Java EE application to rails

Tags: java, mysql, ruby-on-rails

We are in the process of migrating our CRM app built using (JBoss AS, JDBC, Hibernate, MySQL) into Rails 3.2.x

We would like to keep the database schema as it is, so that we have minimal effort while we move into a new web architecture with Rails. Are there any tools which will help me generate the models/controllers and handle migrations from a database perspective.

What strategy should we use so that we can keep the old application humming in production before we move to the newer Rails app.

Comment: You don't migrate an application from a compiled and highly optimized development platform to an interpreted one with a completely different design and language behind it. Java at least is C-based, Ruby on the other hand is designed to be everything BUT C-based. I wish you good luck completely and utterly rebuilding the entire application from scratch.

Comment: I agree with @Gimby in general. Your only option is to start from scratch with the application however, there's no reason why you can't connect this to your existing database. Google 'using rails with an existing database'. There's a million results.

Comment: My intention is to build the entire app from scratch and just re-use only the existing db. Not sure if I need to make changes to the column names also. Sorry If I wasn't clear on the original post.

Comment: Why would you do that? Sounds like someone just doesn't like java...

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I think, and what I have done the same past :)

1 - first write the models coupling with your existing DB (I think you are using ActiveRecord with Rails , if not you should :D)

2 - Try your level best to use ActiveRecord and its components, avoid using pure SQL, because later that will create a mess

3 - cover with good unit tests and make sure your models are working with existing DB and all the relations etc.

4 - then move to the controller and view layer

5 - **Golden rule, try to keep Rails conventions as much as possible, because the beauty of rails is that, if you follow the rails way things will "just work"**

(Since you are using the same database you will not have the headache of data migration).

And +1 migrating from Java to Ruby :)

Comment: I am planning to use ActiveRecord with Rails. The existing column name conventions don't align with what people use with Rails in general (e.g. existing table name is user and not users, date is called cre_date instead of created_at). How should I handle this?

Comment: How about handling auto increment of primary key(s). If I replicate the original db and make changes will there be a guarantee that these id(s) will be unique across the replicated instance also.

Comment: Any suggestions on the view layer. Should I use erb OR HAML or something else, if we intend to expose some portions of the app in mobiles.

Comment: Hi , you will need to override the default Activerecord behaviour like using :set_table_name for table names etc.. initially I believe you should write your own auto_increment method and call it before_create in model. and for view layer I recommend to use 'twitter bootstrap' as its optimized for mobile and use .erb (coz later you could move to .haml , one change at a time :)) (http://jonathanhui.com/ruby-rails-3-model-working-legacy-database)

Comment: Check [slim](http://www.slim-lang.com) as a templating language, but making displaying work on mobiles does not depend on either of your HTML preprocessors.